# how to build local MySQL server within my C# application

Tags: c#, mysql

I have been tasked with writing C# software using MySQL Database. now i installed Wamp Server and every thing is OK.
and i will use advanced installer to build it.
My question then is; what is the best copy or plugin of MySQL server to build 
 it with my software.
and how i can start an instance of MySQL on a specific port when loading the application, then shut down the instance when the software is closed?

Comment: If you want a SQL database to start and stop with your program, you might want to use a portable database like SQLite instead.

Comment: i need my software to work on network so i need MySQL server.

Comment: If its running over a network where multiple clients are connected to one database you definitly dont want to start \ stop the MqSql server when one client opens\closes

Comment: that is what i need .
i need my application work on network , but all client computers can't access the database when the copy(my application) which installed on the server PC is closed.

 i need the best version to install it side by side my application without any hard steps to install it ( i will install it only in the main pc).